# MySQL query doesn't run within cronjob

Tags: mysql, bash, terminal

My problem is that this:

`mysql -u root -pmypassword -D cache -e "DELETE FROM cache WHERE job IN('SET', 'UO', 'AV');"`

MySQL query  doesn't run with the cronjob. I am sure that the cronjob starts itself because rest of the code (mysqldump) is running.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

mysql -u mysql-u1494 -pmy-password -D cache -e "DELETE FROM cache WHERE job IN('SET', 'UO', 'AV');"

/usr/local/bin/mysqldump --skip-lock-tables --ignore-table=log.log --user="mysql-u1494" --password="my-password" names > dump.sql
```

When I run this command manually inside of the terminal it works fine. So the question is, **why doesn't this query run?**

Comment: Possible authentication problem, my first wild guess. Have you looked at the MySQL log(s) for other clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probable causes are

1. because you didn't provide a full path for mysql
2. your password contains characters that need to be escaped

Try to change

```
mysql -u mysql-u1494 -pmy-password -D cache -e "DELETE FROM cache WHERE job IN('SET', 'UO', 'AV');"
```

to

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql -u mysql-u1494 -p"my-password" -D cache -e "DELETE FROM cache WHERE job IN('SET', 'UO', 'AV');"
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                        ^           ^
```

Comment: Argh. Yes - thats was the problem. Thank you Peter. Will accept the answer within 5 minutes.